# Any help to convert this chain of query in a single bulk instruction?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bulk

On a NodeJs application, I've a snippet which:

```
- check if an element exist (1 query)
- if present, update some value of it (1 query)
- else, add a new record (1 query) and delete an older one (1 query)
```

So basically 4 query for a "single" task. Here's my complete code:

```
let candleData;
try {
    candleData = await Candle.findOne({ instrument_name: instrumentName, exchangeType: exchangeType, dt: dt });
    if (!candleData) {
        try {
            // add new candle
            let newCandle = {
                instrument_name: instrumentName,
                exchangeType: exchangeType,
                dt: dt,
                o: o,
                h: h,
                l: l,
                c: c
            }
            await Candle.create(newCandle);

            // remove older candle
            await Candle.deleteMany({ instrument_name: instrumentName, exchangeType: exchangeType, dt: { $lt: dtOlder } });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        // update candle
        candleData.c = c;
        await candleData.save();
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
}
```

Can I convert it as bulk operation? And improve the whole chain?

**Note:** I'm finding/removing different items. The "where" are different. I find for dt=dt and remove for dt lower than dtOlder. So its not really the same. So its not an upsert instruction.

Here's some document to have some test:

```
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "62c40373d08fcf4ca03eb4b4"  },  "instrument_name": "BTCBUSD",  "exchangeType": "BINANCE",  "dt": 1657005300000,  "o": "20264.80000000",  "h": "20290.73000000",  "l": "20178.66000000",  "c": "20211.63000000"}
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "62c40373d08fcf4ca03eb4b5"  },  "instrument_name": "BTCBUSD",  "exchangeType": "BINANCE",  "dt": 1657006200000,  "o": "20213.33000000",  "h": "20218.26000000",  "l": "20155.26000000",  "c": "20202.61000000"}
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "62c40373d08fcf4ca03eb4b6"  },  "instrument_name": "BTCBUSD",  "exchangeType": "BINANCE",  "dt": 1657007100000,  "o": "20202.61000000",  "h": "20238.23000000",  "l": "20172.76000000",  "c": "20192.74000000"}
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "62c40373d08fcf4ca03eb4b7"  },  "instrument_name": "BTCBUSD",  "exchangeType": "BINANCE",  "dt": 1657008000000,  "o": "20192.75000000",  "h": "20192.75000000",  "l": "20033.95000000",  "c": "20090.00000000"}
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "62c40373d08fcf4ca03eb4b8"  },  "instrument_name": "BTCBUSD",  "exchangeType": "BINANCE",  "dt": 1657008900000,  "o": "20090.00000000",  "h": "20098.49000000",  "l": "19930.00000000",  "c": "19989.98000000"}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about where `dtOlder` requirement comes from but have you looked at performing an `updateOne()` operation? The `{ upsert: true }` option will determine whether to perform an insert or update in a single operation. See the MongoDB documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/upsert/

Comment: @DanNagle it will still miss the delete part (i.e. remove the old one). dtOlder (as for dt) are two datetime timestamp evaluated before run the snippet

Comment: Edited the question, writing more details that could be misunderstand (i.e. is not a upsert function)

Comment: It can be done in one aggregation pipeline if you are willing to replace the entire document instead of delete and add (last 2 queries)

Comment: @nimrodserok uhm yes, I could "update" the one I want to delete with the data of new record, that of course. Any example?

Comment: Please provide 3-4 documents to play with, and I'll write an aggregation pipeline

Comment: @nimrodserok I did (written on the question)

Comment: OK, after trying, I agree with others here. I was mistaken. I could not find a better solution for this case, as there are multiple documents to delete. I considered a deletion of one which I wanted to replace instead of delete.

Comment: @nimrodserok not sure what you mean. consider that the task will always (every time) add 1 and delete 1. maybe is the deleteMany which make confusion? I think it will work the same using deleteOne. Will this help?

Comment: Yes, It should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of documents that need to be deleted is one or zero, you can do it in one query. Something like:

1. `$match` the common ground. If a situation that there is no match here is reasonable, this should be inserted into both branches of the `$facet`
2. differ the two cases `found`/`notFound` using `$facet`. If found, replace the wanted fields, if not, limit the updated (needs to be deleted) document to 1.
3. format and updated the `notFound` case to a new document using the "deleted" document _id.
4. use `$ifNull` to set one new document to update according to our case: `found`/`notFound`.
5. use `$merge` to update the document (all cases end in one updated document).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {instrument_name: instrument_name, exchangeType: exchangeType}},
  {
    $facet: {
      found: [{$match: {dt: dt}}, {$set: {c: c}}],
      notFound: [{$match: {dt: {$lt: dtOlder }}}, {$limit: 1}]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      found: {$first: "$found"},
      notFound: {$mergeObjects: [
        {$first: "$notFound"}, 
        {dt: dt, o: o, h: h, l: l, c: c, instrument_name: instrumentName,
         exchangeType: exchangeType}]}
    }
  },
  {$project: {newObj: {$ifNull: ["$found", "$notFound"]}}},
  {$merge: {into: "collection"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ODeELKGKP0c)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.candleData.updateOne(
   { instrument_name: instrumentName, exchangeType: exchangeType, dt: dt },
   {
      $set: { c: c },
      $setOnInsert: {
         instrument_name: instrumentName,
         exchangeType: exchangeType,
         dt: dt,
         o: o,
         h: h,
         l: l
      }
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

Ensure that the filter matches a single document only.

Comment: Where is the delete part?

Comment: "update" should be the same as "delete + insert". Why do you like to delete anything?

Comment: Note I'm removing different items. The "where" are different. I find for dt=dt and remove for dt lower than dtOlder. So its not really the same...

Comment: Then you may review your data design. Otherwise you need to stick with 4 individual tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If your situation is not appropriate to use `upsert`, `MongoDB Realm Function` or `Database Trigger`,
I think your logic is reasonable.